# Is there a PostgreSQL function that calculates the percentage difference from the first row only?

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage

I am looking for a PostgreSQL function like PERCENT_RANK() or CUME_DIST() or similar to lag() that will take the first row only and calculate the percentage of every number from the first number. Like this:

| page | number | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7347618 | 100.00% |
| 1 | 6872759 | 93.54% |
| 2 | 5702997 | 77.62% |
| 3 | 4914545 | 66.89% |
| 4 | 4702129 | 64.00% |

I was trying to solve it with lag() like this but didn't find any way to fix the page==0.

```
select
page,
number as page_impressions,
number::DECIMAL/lag(number)
over(partition by page=0)
from my_table
group by page
order by page
```

Is there a way to make lag() work like this or is there a built-in function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `first_value` and not `lag`

```
SELECT "page", "number"
     , round(100 * "number"::numeric /
             first_value("number") OVER (ORDER BY "page")
             , 2) AS percentage
FROM my_table
```